# Configuring AWS Signing in Reactive Elasticsearch Configuration

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, webclient, spring-data-elasticsearch, reactor

In one of our service I tried to configure AWS signing in Spring data Reactive Elasticsearch configuration.
Spring provides the configuring the webclient through webclientClientConfigurer

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
  .connectedTo("localhost:9200")                      
  .usingSsl()                                                                                                    
  .withWebClientConfigurer(                                                
    webClient -> {
      return webClient.mutate().filter(new AwsSigningInterceptor()).build();
    })
  . // ... other options to configure if required
  .build();
```

through which we can configure to sign the requests but however [AWS signing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html) it requires url, queryparams, headers and request body(in case of POST,POST) to generate the signed headers.

Using this I created a simple exchange filter function to sign the request but in this function I was not able to access the request body and use it.
Below is the Filter function i was trying to use

```
@Component
public class AwsSigningInterceptor implements ExchangeFilterFunction
{
    private final AwsHeaderSigner awsHeaderSigner;

    public AwsSigningInterceptor(AwsHeaderSigner awsHeaderSigner)
    {
        this.awsHeaderSigner = awsHeaderSigner;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next)
    {
        Map<String, List<String>> signingHeaders = awsHeaderSigner.createSigningHeaders(request, new byte[]{}, "es", "us-west-2"); // should pass request body bytes in place of new byte[]{}

        ClientRequest.Builder requestBuilder = ClientRequest.from(request);

        signingHeaders.forEach((key, value) -> requestBuilder.header(key, value.toArray(new String[0])));

        return next.exchange(requestBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

I also tried to access the request body inside ExchangeFilterFunction using below approach but once i get the request body using below approach.

```
ClientRequest.from(newRequest.build())
            .body(
                (outputMessage, context) -> {
                  ClientHttpRequestDecorator loggingOutputMessage =
                      new ClientHttpRequestDecorator(outputMessage) {

                        @Override
                        public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
                          log.info("Inside write with method");
                          body =
                              DataBufferUtils.join(body)
                                  .map(
                                      content -> {
                                        // Log request body using
                                        // 'content.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)'
                                        String requestBody =
                                            content.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                                        
                                        Map<String, Object> signedHeaders =
                                            awsSigner.getSignedHeaders(
                                                request.url().getPath(),
                                                request.method().name(),
                                                multimap,
                                                requestHeadersMap,
                                                Optional.of(
                                                    requestBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

                                        log.info("Signed Headers generated:{}", signedHeaders);
                                        signedHeaders.forEach(
                                            (key, value) -> {
                                              newRequest.header(key, value.toString());
                                            });
                                        return content;
                                      });
                          log.info("Before returning the body");
                          return super.writeWith(body);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Mono<Void>
                            setComplete() { // This is for requests with no body (e.g. GET).
                          
                          Map<String, Object> signedHeaders =
                              awsSigner.getSignedHeaders(
                                  request.url().getPath(),
                                  request.method().name(),
                                  multimap,
                                  requestHeadersMap,
                                  Optional.of("".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

                          log.info("Signed Headers generated:{}", signedHeaders);
                          signedHeaders.forEach(
                              (key, value) -> {
                                newRequest.header(key, value.toString());
                              });

                          return super.setComplete();
                        }
                      };

                  return originalBodyInserter.insert(loggingOutputMessage, context);
                })
            .build();
```

But with above approach I was not able to change the request headers as adding headers throws UnsupportedOperationException inside writewith method.

Has anyone used the spring data reactive elastic search and configured to sign with AWS signed headers?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring WebClient: Automatically compute HMAC signature for body and pass it as header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381316/spring-webclient-automatically-compute-hmac-signature-for-body-and-pass-it-as-h)

Comment: @ChinHuang I tried this approach as well mentioned but the BodyProvidingJsonEncoder( which implements Jackson2JsonEncoder) is not getting called in case of Elasticsearch calls. After debugging i find out that canEncode method in Jackson2JsonEncoder is returning false for ES calls(where String is the elementType) due to which the encode method is not getting called. If I try to override canEncode and pass true value then request body signing is not matching due to encoding and AWS throws error saying the signed headers does not match the calculated signed headers.