# How to intercept Spring WebFlux WebClient request and response with headers and bodies?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, hmac, spring-webclient

I'm working on a Spring Boot application that uses Spring WebFlux, and I'm trying to intercept WebClient requests and responses. Specifically, I need to capture both the headers and the request/response bodies to compute and verify an HMAC.

I've explored the use of `ExchangeFilterFunction`, which allows me to access `ClientHttpRequest` and `ClientHttpResponse` and retrieve the headers. However, I'm facing an issue with capturing the request/response bodies using this approach.

On a `ExchangeFilterFuction`, the request.body() is a `BodyInsert`, is there any way to extract the body from there? Also on the filter, the `response.bodyToMono(String.class)` doesn't retrieve the response body.

On the other hand, I've looked into [using Encoder and Decoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381316/spring-webclient-automatically-compute-hmac-signature-for-body-and-pass-it-as-h), which can help me retrieve the body but do not provide access to the Request/Response objects, making it challenging to obtain the header information.

Have anyone manage to achieve anything related to this?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem...

Comment: you can try to use a `BodyExtractor` as in `response.body(BodyExtractor.toMono(Foobar.class))` and no i dont have a code sample. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors.html